# Sum values based on Unique values in other column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, aggregate-functions, date-arithmetic

I'm working with a table in BigQuery that has millions of lines and I'm trying to reduce the granularity of this data.

My end goal is to have a table looking like this.

| Week | Model | Quantity | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | AA | 5 | 90 |
| 10 | BB | 2 | 40 |
| 11 | CC | 4 | 50 |

- Week : First I want to reduce the number of lines based on Order Date by aggregating the data by week. I believe the following should work for that: `DATE_TRUNC(t.DATE_REQUEST, WEEK(MONDAY)) AS PURCHASE_WEEK_MONDAY_START`
- Model : The Model is not unique, but there can only be one Model per Order Number
- Quantity : The Quantity number is the tricky one as I want to return the MAX Quantity per Order Number. So even though Order Number A23 has three lines of 2 I only want it to return the number 2 (not 6).
- Price should be SUM for all lines.

> So in the example table above Week 10 has two different Models in AA and BB. AA has a sum of Quantity 5 (MAX for Order Number A23 and B45 is 2 and 3) and the Price 90 is the SUM of the Price lines. BB with Order Number E78 has a MAX Quantity of 2 with a Price SUM of 40.

The original table has the following structure. No null values are allowed.

| Order Date | Order Number | Type | Model | Quantity | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-10 | A23 | Z | AA | 2 | 10 |
| 2023-03-10 | A23 | X | AA | 2 | 20 |
| 2023-03-10 | A23 | Y | AA | 2 | 10 |
| 2023-03-11 | E78 | X | BB | 2 | 20 |
| 2023-03-11 | E78 | Z | BB | 2 | 20 |
| 2023-03-12 | B45 | Y | AA | 3 | 5 |
| 2023-03-12 | B45 | Z | AA | 3 | 15 |
| 2023-03-12 | B45 | X | AA | 3 | 20 |
| 2023-03-12 | B45 | Q | AA | 3 | 10 |
| 2023-03-15 | C56 | X | CC | 1 | 30 |
| 2023-03-15 | C56 | Y | CC | 1 | 5 |
| 2023-03-17 | D89 | Z | CC | 3 | 15 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with two levels of aggregation. First get the maximum of quantity of each week/order/model tuple, then sum by week/order.

```
select purchase_week, model, 
    sum(max_quantity) quantity, 
    sum(sum_price) price
from (
    select
        date_trunc(order_date, ISOWEEK) purchase_week,
        order_number,
        model,
        max(quantity) max_quantity,
        sum(price) sum_price
    from mytable t
    group by purchase_week, order_number, model
) t
group by purchase_week, model
order by purchase_week, model
```

Note: I used `ISOWEEK` to truncate the date; ISO weeks start on Mondays. The first ISO week contains the first Thursday of the year, as explained in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_trunc).